# Hipchat API without auth_token

Tags: c#, api, xmpp

I'm looking for an API in C# that connect with hipchat, using jabber. I do not want to use own API hipchat to not have to create the authentication key (by the admin).

I am wanting to make a windows form client to connect, send and receive messages, etc..

Anyone know any library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of libraries here:
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

HipChat uses XMPP for it's chat layer, so any xmpp standard library should function, as Alex mentioned on his answer. Here's [some documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/hipchatkb/setting-up-xmpp-jabber-clients-for-hipchat-751436251.html) page on how to setup some of the most popular xmpp/jabber clients, along with some limitaions.

If you browse to https://www.hipchat.com/account/xmpp after you login to hipchat, you'll get the connection details of your specific user. Do keep in mind that the ID you need to use for xmpp connections is not your email, but the one listed on the hipchat page.